# Pandas excel like nested countifs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, excel-formula, pandas-groupby

am hitting a block here. I have to translate this excel formula

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(advisor!$C:$C,$A3)=0,"0 disclosed",
IF(COUNTIFS(advisor!$C:$C,$A3,advisor!$E:$E,2)>0,"Dependent",
IF(IF(COUNTIFS(advisor!$C:$C,$A3,advisor!$B:$B,"auditor")>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTIFS(advisor!$C:$C,$A3,advisor!$B:$B,"compensation")>0,1,0)=2,"Independent","1 disclosed")))
```

so far this is my python-pandas solution:

```
df['auditor_compensation'] = np.where(df['id'].isin(df_advisor['company_id']).count() == 0,
                                          '0 disclosed',
                                          np.where(df_advisor['dependent'] == 2, 'dependent',
                                          np.where((np.where(df_advisor['type']=='auditor', 1, 0)+np.where(df_advisor['type']=='compensation', 1, 0)) == 2, 'independent', '1 disclosed')))
```

which i keep getting `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

**df** sample data: company data

```
id      ticker       iq_id     company              auditor_compensation
48299   ENXTAM:AALB  IQ881736   Aalberts Industries       ?
48752   ENXTAM:ABN   IQ1090191  ABN AMRO Group            ?
48865   ENXTAM:ACCEL IQ4492981  Accell Group              ?
49226   ENXTAM:AGN   IQ247906   AEGON                     ?
49503   ENXTAM:AD    IQ373545   Koninklijke               ?
```

below is **df_advisor** sample data

```
id    type          company_id  advisor_company_id  dependent
1     auditor       4829        6091                    1
17    auditor       4875        16512                   1
6359  auditor       4886        7360                    1
37    auditor       4922        8187                    1
4415  compensation  4922        9025                    1
53    auditor       4950        8187                    1
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: There is no `df_advisor['dependent']`?

Comment: So, just to be clear, this works in excel and is not an excel problem.

Comment: @Hoenie There is `df_advisor['dependent']` column, I've added it to the question now

Comment: Check the return vector length of the `np.where` summation and consider how data may have been duplicated or dropped. That'd be a decent place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `numpy.where` function doesn't generate an array or series with the same length as the original dataframe. This is because it's trying to combine inconsistent conditions, e.g. `df['id']` and `df_advisor['dependent']` will have different lengths.

While it's tempting to translate your Excel formula to Pandas / NumPy, using [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) will likely be more efficient and readable.

**Step 1: Group mapping dataframe**

```
df_advisor_grouped = df_advisor.groupby('company_id')\
                               .agg({'type': '|'.join, 'dependent': 'sum'})\
                               .reset_index()

print(df_advisor_grouped)

   company_id                  type  dependent
0        4829               auditor          1
1        4875               auditor          1
2        4886               auditor          1
3        4922  auditor|compensation          2
4        4950               auditor          1
```

**Step 2: Merge with main dataframe**

```
# merge dataframes based on key column
res = df.merge(df_advisor_grouped, left_on='id', right_on='company_id', how='left')
```

**Step 3: Apply conditional logic**

```
# define 3 conditions
conds = [res['company_id'].isnull(), res['dependent'].eq(2),
         res['type'].str.contains('auditor') & res['type'].str.contains('compensation')]

# define 3 choices
choices = ['0 disclosed', 'dependent', 'independent'] 

# apply np.select logic, including default argument if 3 conditions are not met
res['auditor_compensation'] = np.select(conds, choices, '1 disclosed')
```

Comment: Very comprehensible and I managed to learn a couple of tricks..which points to the right direction. 

**Step 2**: is done with `df` and `df_advisor_grouped` right?

Thanks a lot man!